# Javascript targeting the first element only with a double click issue

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JavaScript at the moment (started 3 weeks ago at college) and i'm struggling to create a mobile menu whereby you click and that reveals or hides a hidden menu.

The issue here is that JS only targets the first class and not all of them. And you need to click twice to reveal the element that does work.

I would be very grateful for some guidance, and hopefully an expiation to help me understand the problem.

Thank you

```
<script>
const btn = document.querySelector('.navigation-main-mobile .menu-item-has-children');
const box = document.querySelector('.navigation-main-mobile .menu-item-has-children .sub-menu');

btn.addEventListener('click', function handleClick() {
if (box.style.display === 'none') {
    box.style.display = 'block';
} else {
    box.style.display = 'none';
}
});
</script>

<ul id="menu-primary-menu" class="navigation-main-mobile"><li><a href="/">Text</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="#">Text</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="http://1.io/1/1/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://1.io/2/2/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://1.io/3/3/">Text</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="/news/" aria-current="page"></a>Text</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="#"></a>Text</a></li>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="http://1.io/4/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://1.io/5/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://1.io/6/">Text</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about/">Text</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If i'm thinking about this all wrong then please tell me :)

Comment: `.querySelector` only returns the first element that matches, if you want them all you'll need `querySelectorAll` and then someway to iterate or target the relevant element in the returned NodeList. The reason it takes two clicks is that on the first click the element doesn't have a `style.display` attribute at all and so the first click sets `box.style.display = 'none';` and the second click works as expected. There are duplicates for both, I'll need to find them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to find all nodes which match the selector. `querySelectorAll` is used for that. Then you must loop through all the nodes and set the event.
Also, you have to remove the wrong closing `<li>` tag (which messes up the selector) after `</a>Text</a>` in the second `menu-item-has-children`

```
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.navigation-main-mobile .menu-item-has-children');
const boxs = document.querySelectorAll('.navigation-main-mobile .menu-item-has-children .sub-menu');


btns.forEach((btn, index) => {
btn.addEventListener('click', function handleClick() {
if (boxs[index].style.display === 'none') {
    boxs[index].style.display = 'block';
} else {
    boxs[index].style.display = 'none';
}
})});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I didn't know about querySelectorAll. So I'll need to use that and loop through. I'll try and build that and will compare with your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. `.querySelector()` returns the first element that matches the values passed.
2. You are getting the double click issue because you have not set a value for the `style.display` attribute. When you click it for the first time the browser realized that and set the attribute to `none` and then the second click performs the changes that you coded.

Remember to be somewhat explicit in what you want to code and do not assume that the computer is going to complete anything for you. Good Luck!